# I'm using dynamic routing with vue router in vue js but can't get data by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using dynamic router to navigate from dashboard to detail page, in URL bar still get id but it doesn't work for detail page and console gives error : GET http://localhost:1337/jobinfos/undefined
Here is code my overview page

**Jobs.vue:**

```
<div class="job-item" v-for="(item, index) in showJobs" :key="index">
          <a href=""
            ><h3 class="mleft-27">{{ item.position }}</h3></a
          >
                <img src="../assets/recruit/years.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.exprerience }}</b>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/luong.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.salary }}</b>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/diadiem.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.headequarters }}</b>
              <h6>{{ item.createdAt }}</h6>
            <div class="list-info-job" v-html="item.content">
           <router-link tag="a" :to="`/detail/${item.id}`">
              <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
            </router-link>
          </div>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export defaul{
methods: {
    async getJobs() {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },
}
</script
```

And here is the job detail page, i tried to set id = 1 instead of this.id and console.log got the data but it still can't display those data..

```
<div class="info-detail" v-for="(item, index) in jobinfos" :key="index">
            <div>
              <h6>Job Requirements</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.requirements">
                 
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-detail">
            <div>
              <h6>Skills</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.skills"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-detail">
            <div>
              <h6>Interests</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.interests"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export defaul{
 props:['id'],
mounted(){
    this.getdetail();
  
  },
methods: {
   async getdetail() {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos/` + this.id)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },
}
</script>
```

Hope to get help from everyone...thanks ^^

Comment: I think the flaw is that you think the `id` will be a  `props` property rather than a `$route.params` property ... assuming you're using `vue-router` and have set up the `/detail` route correctly of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the id from the router. For this to work, you first need to [define your dynamic route in your routes file](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), like:

```
{
  path: '/product/:id',
  component: JobDetail, /// example, use your detail component
}
```

Now, when you navigate to /product/1, the id will be set as a param in the router. So in the JobDetail component, you can get it by using `const id = this.$route.params.id`. You can use this in your `getdetail` method:

```
async getdetail() {
   const id = this.$route.params.id
   await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos/` + id)
      .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
          console.log(response.data)
       })
       .catch((e) => {});
},
```

You can remove `id` as a prop, as it is unused.

Hope this helps.

PS:
Another small remark on your code: in your Jobs.vue you use `index` as a key for `v-for`. This is not recommended, because when the `showJobs` array changes, the index of the items inside will change. Therefore, vue cannot track which element was deleted or added and will need to completely rerender the `v-for` again. You should use a unique key, like `item.id`. This will stay always stay the same and vue will only rerender the change.

Comment: I have one more problem that under detailed job there is another list of different jobs when I reuse dynamic router like previous page it doesn't reload page and data....hope hope you can give me the solution, thanks

Comment: Would it be possible that you create another question for that? With the code of the component and the router. And a description of the behaviour you're after and currently getting. Just comment on this answer with the link to the new question and I will take a look.